# Will Apple permit application with Android image in it

Tags: ios, iphone

I've heard that Apple rejects applications which have word "Android" in them.
My question is will Apple permit application which have icon of Android?

My application have specific functionality which differs when we are talking about Apple devices and Android devices on the second end. So i have icon of Apple + label "iOS" and icon of Android + label "non-iOS" and user can choose between these two options before connecting to his friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently got one of my apps rejected, just because the launch image consisted an Android device(along with an iPhone). I would say , play it safe and remove all the android references from your app. Take an example of the Bump app. It's USP is data transfer between devices of different platforms, but nowhere in it's iOS app(even the launch image), is any other platform represented.